# How to correctly switch between two UIViews by using segment control ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to switch between two `UIViews` using `segmentControl`.Now both of these `UIViews` have embedded `scrollView` of their own.These `UIViews` are supposed to appear as one , so I have placed them on top of each other (in XIB) .And when `segmentControl` is clicked I am trying to hide / show them accordingly.  But so far I am unable to switch between the two.Also tried solution suggested below .However it only works in **random** cells and fails to switch in all cells.What is missing ?

This is how I set the upper view hidden in `didSelectRow` where I am expanding the `tableViewCell` .

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {

    expCell.upperContainer.hidden = NO;
    expCell.upperScroll.hidden = NO;
    [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];

     }else{
    isExpanded=YES;
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];

    //hide upper container

    if (!expCell.upperContainer.hidden) {

        expCell.upperContainer.hidden = YES;


    }
    if (!expCell.upperScroll.hidden) {

        expCell.upperScroll.hidden =YES;
    }

   }

  [self.bTableView beginUpdates];
  [self.bTableView reloadData];
  [self.bTableView endUpdates];
 }
```

And in expandedCell on segmentControl click I am doing the following.

```
-(void)selectDeckView:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{

if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
     NSLog(@"segment 0");             //executes
     expCell.lowerDeckView.hidden=NO;
     expCell.lowerScrollView.hidden=NO;
     expCell.upperScroll.hidden=YES;
     expCell.upperContainer.hidden=YES;

}else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
    NSLog(@"segment 1");                //executes
    expCell.lowerDeckView.hidden=YES;
    expCell.lowerScrollView.hidden=YES;
    expCell.upperContainer.hidden=NO;
    expCell.upperScroll.hidden=NO;


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having each view in its own view controller, then add the appropriate child view controller whenever a segment is pressed.

Your view controller that contains the segmented control would be the container view controller, and it would have a method like this that adds one of your two content view controllers (with each containing one of the views you mentioned), which gets invoked when a segment is pressed:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content; 
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

You could cache your child view controller instances so that they only get created once, if that is appropriate, meaning it will be fast.  Apple's documentation on content/child view controllers:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Yes I thought about that too.Unfortunately my views are placed in XIB now as is my expanded table cell.How do I add child view in this case, if that's even possible.

Comment: You could just split them into separate nibs, then create a child view controller for each nib by doing something like this:    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];

Comment: Giving a try to your solution.I have a question though.Since I was populating the views in my current view controller with current implementation.Can I populate the childViewControllers views from my parent view controller and then just load them? Or anything else is to be done?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that.  Personally I'd probably pass a model object into the child view controller (and therefore have each child be a UIViewController subclass) that populates the views.  Remember that it's important to not just add the child view controller's view, you also have to call addChildViewController, and didMoveToParentViewController, as described in my answer, otherwise you'll run across some problems with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you might have a view that covers the other,have you tried:

```
if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
     NSLog(@"segment 0");             //executes
     expCell.lowerDeckView.hidden=NO;
     expCell.lowerScrollView.hidden=NO;
     expCell.upperScroll.hidden=YES;
     expCell.upperContainer.hidden=YES;
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:expCell.upperScroll]
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:expCell.upperContainer]

}else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
    NSLog(@"segment 1");                //executes
    expCell.lowerDeckView.hidden=YES;
    expCell.lowerScrollView.hidden=YES;
    expCell.upperContainer.hidden=NO;
    expCell.upperScroll.hidden=NO;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:expCell.lowerScrollView]
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:expCell.lowerDeckView]


}

}
```

make sure that you bring them to the front in the correct order.

Comment: it actually worked in first cell only..after that in subsequent cells doesn't switch.